# Hibernate: table lock with a select?

Tags: java, hibernate, locks

I have this method that selects a row from table product_customer:

```
public static String getQuoziente(String pcCustomer, String pcAccountNumber, String prodCode) {
    String quoziente=null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    try {
        String sql = String.format("SELECT pc_quoziente FROM product_customer " +
                "WHERE pc_customer=:cliente and pc_account_number=:numacc  and pc_prod_desc=:prod");
        quoziente = (String) session.createSQLQuery(sql)
                .setParameter("cliente", pcCustomer)
                .setParameter("numacc", pcAccountNumber)
                .setParameter("prod", prodCode)
                .uniqueResult();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return quoziente;
}
```

After this query try to truncate the table from MySqlWorkbench with:

```
TRUNCATE wla.product_customer;
```

But truncate is blocked from a lock and never ends.
Why should a simple select row lock the table?

PS: i can delete rows with DELETE, only truncate is locked

Comment: This question  does not related to Hibernate. I think you datasorce configured that way. But it is wild guess.

Comment: Can you post your HBM file or Entity class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to commit the transaction in the code before you run a TRUNCATE statement.
MySQL maintains metadata locks, and if there is a lock from a DML statement, it needs to be released through a commit before executing a DDL statement (TRUNCATE in this case).
SELECT and DELETE are DML statements and TRUNCATE is a DDL statement. So, you'll be able to execute DELETE but not TRUNCATE unless lock is release.

Comment: There is no explicit transaction in this method, how can i commit it?
Should begin transaction and commit it explicitly? 

     `session.beginTransaction(); `

I thought that open() and close() session was enough.

Comment: You can try setting autocommit to true if you just want to see how it changes the behavior. But, it is recommended to set your transaction boundaries explicitly. Said that, database engines execute every statement under a transaction context even though it is a SELECT statement, but different DBs handle transactions to commit or rollback differently for non-transactional data accesses. AFAIK Hibernate does not commit a transaction on its own. So, here Hibernate opens a JDBC transaction but is never closed actually, although connection is returned to the connection pool after close().